# How to cross-compile raspicam code?

Tags: camera, raspicam

How do you cross compile C code for controlling the Raspberry Pi camera on an x86 platform?

I'm trying to create a unittest for compiling and testing the code on a generic x86 continuous integration server (but obviously not connecting to the camera) but I get [an error](https://travis-ci.org/chrisspen/raspicam_node/jobs/199254992) for a missing vcos library:

```
/home/travis/catkin_ws/src/raspicam_node/src/RaspiCamControl.cpp:32:33: fatal error: interface/vcos/vcos.h: No such file or directory

 #include "interface/vcos/vcos.h"

                                 ^

compilation terminated.

/home/travis/catkin_ws/src/raspicam_node/src/RaspiCLI.cpp:46:33: fatal error: interface/vcos/vcos.h: No such file or directory

 #include "interface/vcos/vcos.h"

                                 ^
```

As far as I can see, this library is only available in the repos for the Raspiberry Pi, and have no x86 candidates in the standard Ubuntu repos. How do I fix this?

Edit: I managed to fix all the include errors by manually installing the [Raspberry Pi firmware headers](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware) to my /opt/vc.

It now seems to compile my code fine, but it's failing to link it to some shared objects:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target raspicam_node
Scanning dependencies of target raspicam_raw_node
[ 25%] Building CXX object raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_node.dir/src/raspicam_node.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_raw_node.dir/src/raspicam_raw_node.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable /tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_raw_node
[100%] Linking CXX executable /tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_node
/opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_raw_node.dir/build.make:174: recipe for target '/tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_raw_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_raw_node] Error 1
raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_node.dir/build.make:174: recipe for target '/tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/raspicam_node_test/catkin_ws/devel/lib/raspicam/raspicam_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:362: recipe for target 'raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_raw_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_raw_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:783: recipe for target 'raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [raspicam/CMakeFiles/raspicam_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I'm assuming this is because the *.so objects in my /opt/vc/lib directory are compiled for ARM whereas my makefile is compiling for the localhost's architecture, which is amd64? How do I specify architecture in a CMakelist?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi specific files have no purpose on other platforms, that's why Ubuntu is not hosting them.

VideoCore OS files can be found [here](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/tree/master/dependencies/vcos).

Comment: That has some of the includes, but not all. I'm still missing bcm_host.h. Googling shows that's included in the package `libraspberrypi-dev`, but that package is only available on Raspbian, not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Cerin I suggest you limit your search to RPi github. I have found `bcm_host.h` twice there: [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/libs/bcm_host/include) and [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/include). Not sure which one you may need though.